# Unable to login during boot without reinstalling Graphic drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

My system has a recurring problem where I am unable to login after certain packages have been updated. Below is s list the most recently install packages taken from `/var/log/dpkg.log` and upon reboot I was unable to login using the GUI.

```
2015-02-25 10:36:39 install linux-image-3.13.0-46-generic:amd64 <none> 3.13.0-46.75
2015-02-25 10:36:41 install linux-headers-3.13.0-46:all <none> 3.13.0-46.75
2015-02-25 10:36:44 install linux-headers-3.13.0-46-generic:amd64 <none> 3.13.0-46.75
2015-02-25 10:36:45 install linux-image-extra-3.13.0-46-generic:amd64 <none> 3.13.0-46.75
2015-02-25 10:36:50 install linux-signed-image-3.13.0-46-generic:amd64 <none> 3.13.0-46.75
```

This also happen on the 18th of February during the update of different packages. This log is from Synaptic.

```
Commit Log for Wed Feb 18 00:37:15 2015


Upgraded the following packages:
apport (2.14.1-0ubuntu3.6) to 2.14.1-0ubuntu3.7
apport-gtk (2.14.1-0ubuntu3.6) to 2.14.1-0ubuntu3.7
compiz (1:0.9.11.3+14.04.20141104-0ubuntu1+ppa2) to 1:0.9.11.3+14.04.20150122-0ubuntu1
compiz-core (1:0.9.11.3+14.04.20141104-0ubuntu1+ppa2) to 1:0.9.11.3+14.04.20150122-0ubuntu1
compiz-gnome (1:0.9.11.3+14.04.20141104-0ubuntu1+ppa2) to 1:0.9.11.3+14.04.20150122-0ubuntu1
compiz-plugins-default (1:0.9.11.3+14.04.20141104-0ubuntu1+ppa2) to 1:0.9.11.3+14.04.20150122-0ubuntu1
gir1.2-gudev-1.0 (1:204-5ubuntu20.9) to 1:204-5ubuntu20.10
libcompizconfig0 (1:0.9.11.3+14.04.20141104-0ubuntu1+ppa2) to 1:0.9.11.3+14.04.20150122-0ubuntu1
libdecoration0 (1:0.9.11.3+14.04.20141104-0ubuntu1+ppa2) to 1:0.9.11.3+14.04.20150122-0ubuntu1
libfreetype6 (2.5.2-1ubuntu2.2) to 2.5.2-1ubuntu2.3
libgudev-1.0-0 (1:204-5ubuntu20.9) to 1:204-5ubuntu20.10
liblightdm-gobject-1-0 (1.10.3-0ubuntu2) to 1.10.4-0ubuntu2
libpam-systemd (204-5ubuntu20.9) to 204-5ubuntu20.10
libsystemd-daemon0 (204-5ubuntu20.9) to 204-5ubuntu20.10
libsystemd-journal0 (204-5ubuntu20.9) to 204-5ubuntu20.10
libsystemd-login0 (204-5ubuntu20.9) to 204-5ubuntu20.10
libudev1 (204-5ubuntu20.9) to 204-5ubuntu20.10
libudev1:i386 (204-5ubuntu20.9) to 204-5ubuntu20.10
lightdm (1.10.3-0ubuntu2) to 1.10.4-0ubuntu2
python3-apport (2.14.1-0ubuntu3.6) to 2.14.1-0ubuntu3.7
python3-problem-report (2.14.1-0ubuntu3.6) to 2.14.1-0ubuntu3.7
systemd-services (204-5ubuntu20.9) to 204-5ubuntu20.10
udev (204-5ubuntu20.9) to 204-5ubuntu20.10
x11-common (1:7.7+1ubuntu8) to 1:7.7+1ubuntu8.1
xorg (1:7.7+1ubuntu8) to 1:7.7+1ubuntu8.1
xserver-xorg (1:7.7+1ubuntu8) to 1:7.7+1ubuntu8.1
xserver-xorg-input-all (1:7.7+1ubuntu8) to 1:7.7+1ubuntu8.1
xserver-xorg-video-all (1:7.7+1ubuntu8) to 1:7.7+1ubuntu8.1
```

The main problem of not being able to login can be fixed easily in 5 minutes entering the TTY with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and reinstalling the graphics drivers with:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
cd ~/Downloads
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-346.35.run
sudo reboot
```

My question is, does anyone know why this happens and potentially how to stop it happening in the future. My best theory is that updating either the kernel or xorg changes something that breaks my graphics drivers.

I am using the Nvidia 346.35 64 bit proprietary drivers downloaded from nvidia.com and my graphics card is a GeForce GTX 970.

---

The issue seems to be a problem with DKMS, however, when installing the Nvidia drivers if I select the `yes` option on `Would you like to register the kernel module sources with DKMS? This will allow DKMS to automaticalty build a new module, if you install a different kernel later.` I get the error below.

```
ERROR: Unable to load the kernal module!

[25961, 788963] systemd-udevd[1735]: Failed to apply ACL on /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem as of a few days ago (on Kubuntu 14.04), I was already using the xorg-edgers repo to get the GTX970 going initially. It seems to correspond time-wise with the 0-46 kernel update, but booting back into an older kernel (eg 0-40) didn't help at all. Last time I had to pull the GPU and use onboard to fix it -- I suspect I might need to do this again.

Comment: Hi Michael, just an update for you on what I tried: I dropped back to onboard graphics (which worked fine), and while there were a stack of updates from the xorg-edgers repository, it only seemed to help slightly with the GTX970 back in. I can see the glowing "kubuntu" logo on boot, and while there's no visible greeter screen, but if I logged in (typing blind), I could see the desktop at maybe 800x600 resolution. But no updates to the screen after that. So...not much luck unfortunately. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the nvidia driver uses a kernel module.  When the nvidia driver, VirtualBox, ndiswrapper, and one or two other packages are installed, they hook into a system called dkms.  DKMS will automatically build copies of these modules for any new kernel that is installed (after the package manager installs linux-whatever-image and linux-whatever-headers, it runs dkms which rebuilds these modules one-by-one).

So, Ubuntu 14.04 only has nvidia-331 drivers in it's usual packages.  But, the solution if you want dkms to do it's thing and have these newer drivers is to add a new software source: ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa

With xorg-edgers added as a software source, you should find nvidia-346 packages are listed, and indeed newer ones should be listed as they come out.  This repo is meant to for installing newer video drivers than your distro would have otherwise, both stable drivers that are just a bit newer, and "bleeding edge" development versions.  So I wouldn't be surprised if the newest nvidia package doesn't come out same day nvidia releases it.

---

Plan B, if you don't want to do that:  dkms doesn't really need you to have a package to work. Per the man page, it looks as though you can add a arbitrary kernel module source tree into dkms and it'll take care of the rest.  The nvidia .run file places a kernel module build directory somewhere or other, pull it into dkms and it should take care of itself.

Comment: I ended up using xorg-edgers and that solved the issue.